# Counting words using c

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I would like to know why my code isn't compiling properly. What I'm trying to accomplish is counting words. I already have where it asks for spaces but that doesn't work if it's multiple sentences in one string. Because it will count the space after a punctuation mark as a word when the punctuation mark is doing the same.

```
 while (s[n] != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(s[n])) //counts letters
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (isspace(s[n])) //count words
        {
            word++;
        }
        if (s[n] == '.' || s[n] == '?' || s[n] == '!')
        {
            else if (s[n + 1] isspace) //This is the problem
            {
                word--;
            }
            sent++;
            word++;
        }   
        n++;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure that this would be correct, but it's not compiling properly so im kinda just stuck here. from my understanding saying (s[n + 1]) is saying if the letter after the one it is currently checking is a space then see if it is a space, if true then word-- else word++. If this is wrong can you please tell me why.

Comment: You are using else if without a previous if

Comment: There are multiple issues here. One of them is that you have an else if without a corresponding if, another is that `s[n+1] isspace` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In the if loop you first need to write `if()`, only then can you write `else if()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can *compile* without error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()

{

 char s[10] = "";
 int n = 0;
 int count =  0;
 int word = 0;
 int sent = 0;

 while (s[n] != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(s[n])) //counts letters
        {
            count++;
        }
        if (isspace(s[n])) //count words
        {
            word++;
        }
        if (s[n] == '.' || s[n] == '?' || s[n] == '!')
        {
          // What to do here ?
        } 
        else if (isspace(s[n + 1])) 
        {
                word--;
        }
           sent++;
           word++;
     }   
        n++;
}
```